# How do I get the first js object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this

```
 var markersList = document.getElementById('markersList');
 L.MarkerCluster.include({
    spiderfy: function(e) {
    var childMarkers = this.getAllChildMarkers();
    this._group._unspiderfy();
    this._group._spiderfied = this;
    // Fill the markersList.
    markersList.innerHTML = childMarkers
      .map((marker, index) => `<li>Marker ${index + 1}: 
        ${marker.getLatLng()}</li>`)
        .join('');
    // Show the modal.
    console.log(markersList);
    $(".modalResult").modal('show');
  },...
```

The above gives me in console:

```
<li>Marker 1: LatLng(45.49934, 9.37966)</li>
<li>Marker 2: LatLng(45.49934, 9.37966)</li>
```

I need to be able to get as a string `45.49934, 9.37966` since they are the same values, I only need one and I need it as a string as I will have to insert it as an input value later on:

```
<input type="hidden" value="45.49934, 9.37966">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you can extract the lat and lng values from the resut of `getLatLng()` via the following regular expression:

`/(-?\d+.\d*)/gi` passed to `.match()`

This regular expression will extract the two numbers from the result of `getLatLng()`; one for lat and the other for lng, which can then be combined to aquire the `requiredString` that you'd use for the input elements value attribute:

```
{ 
  spiderfy: function(e) {
      var childMarkers = this.getAllChildMarkers();
      this._group._unspiderfy();
      this._group._spiderfied = this;
      // Fill the markersList.

      markersList.innerHTML = childMarkers.map((marker) => 
      `<li>Marker: ${marker.getLatLng()}</li>`).join('');

      // If there are any childMarkers
      if(childMarkers.length > 0) {

        // Match the lat and lng numbers from the string returned by getLatLng()
        const [lat, lng] = `${ childMarkers[0].getLatLng() }`
        .match(/(-?\d+.\d*)/gi);

        // Construct the required string value from the extracted numbers
        const requiredString = `${ lat }, ${ lng }`;

        // Use requiredString to populate the value attribute of the
        // input field in OP
        console.log(requiredString);

      }

      // Show the modal.
      console.log(markersList);
      $(".modalResult").modal('show');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `children`, It like as:

```
markersList.children[0].innerText
```

Comment: Thanks, almost. That gives me `Marker 1: LatLng(45.49934, 9.37966)` but I only need `45.49934, 9.37966`

Comment: @rob.m does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53385881/how-do-i-get-the-first-js-object/53385943#53385943